# Unset removed cart item notice on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, notice

Is there a way to hide/remove the notice "Product removed. Undo?" on the cart page, when the customer removed the item from the cart?

I tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title', '__return_null' );
```

but this only hides the title of the product, that has been removed...

I couldn't find the right hook of the rest of the line ("removed" and "Undo?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unset "`{item_name} removed. Undo?`" notice on cart page, you can trick Woocommerce with the following:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'null_removed_cart_item_message'  );
function null_removed_cart_item_message() {
    // Only on cart page
    if( ! is_cart() ) return;

    // Get the WC notices array stored in WC_Session
    $wc_notices = (array) WC()->session->get( 'wc_notices' );
    $found      = false; // Initializing

    // Check that we have at least one "success" notice type
    if( isset($wc_notices['success']) && sizeof($wc_notices['success']) ) {
        // Loop through "success" notices type
        foreach( $wc_notices['success'] as $key => $wc_notice ) {
            // Remove notices that contain the word "removed" from the array
            if ( strpos($wc_notice, 'removed') !== false ) {
                unset($wc_notices['success']);
                $found = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if( $found ) {
        // Set back the notices array to WC_Session
        WC()->session->set( 'wc_notices', $wc_notices );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Important:** Depending on your installation language, you could need to change the word "removed" in the function code to the one that is convenient in your installation language.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, solved using the following statement:

`add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_removed_notice_type', '__return_null');`

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).