# Hide Woocommerce wc-message: "item*" removed. Undo?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, message

There are many articles that describe how to hide the "Added to Cart" message in Woocommerce, which displays a message in the browser's header after an item is **added**. The solution is to add the following code to the functions.php.

`add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false' );`

I am looking for a similar solution to hide the message that displays after an item is **removed** from the cart: "item*" removed. Undo?

Comment: [Unset removed cart item notice on WooCommerce cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502988/unset-removed-cart-item-notice-on-woocommerce-cart-page/) & https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/9bdafbeb1879a955cc7629d585211638482fd56c/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L617

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i do things wherever I'm finding errors critical...

After the error has popped up
right click on your window
go to inspect elements
copy the style selector of that error
And display it as none using css